# cast message argument objective c

Tags: objective-c

I've got an NSMutableDictionary (p) - via a JSON string - that has a bunch of dates in it (seconds since the epoch). I want to convert them to NSDate. I tried the following:

```
NSDate *created_dt = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[p objectForKey:@"created_dt"]];
```

But I get "sending 'id' to parameter of incompatible type 'NSTimeInveral' (aka 'double')"

What's the syntax that I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` expects an `NSTimeInterval` (which `typedef`ed to a `double`). You pass it an object (the return value of `objectForKey`). This object is probably an NSNumber, so you can simply solve your problem like this:

```
NSDate *created_dt = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[p objectForKey:@"created_dt"] doubleValue]];
```

Comment: Really, because `- (id)objectForKey:(id)aKey` returns `id` :)

Comment: `id` means a pointer to any object. You will have to make the assumption that in this case the object that's being returned is an `NSNumber`. To be on the safe side, you can verify this using introspection as well.